# How to filter big datasets in Geoserver WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, filter, cql-filter, cql

Is there a good way to filter datasets with approx 50,000 features in Geoserver? I'd have to select between 100 and 200 features based on ids. These ids are different from the FeatureIds. Couldn't find an "IN" operator similar to SQL in OGC Filter Encoding Standard. Combining multiple PropertyIsEqualTo operators performs really poorly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah.  In that case, you could use GeoServer's WMS CQL filter support, i.e.:

```
http://<hostname>/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&....&cql_filter=IN ('id_1','id_2','id_3')
```

More information is available at http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/WMS+vendor+parameters

Comment: Great! Didn't know that there is an IN operator in CQL. While trying this with "=" operator, Apache ran into "414 Request-URI Too Long". Maybe the characters saved this way make a difference.

Comment: switch to post instead of get.

Comment: @iant: You're right, POST instead of GET works. The performance remains poor though.

Comment: do you have an index on the FIDs column?

Comment: @iant: I have an index on the id I'm filtering for, but not on the FIDs.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a list of feature id's in the following manner:

GET:

```
http://<hostname>/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=foo&featureid=id_1,id_2,id_3
```

POST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature version="1.1.0" outputFormat="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1" service="WFS" resultType="results" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <wfs:Query typeName="foo">
        <wfs:PropertyName>String</wfs:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="id_1"/>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="id_2"/>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="id_3"/>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

The POST option is obviously more verbose, but less than looping PropertyIsEqualTo constructs.

Comment: That looks like a good solution for filtering FeatureIds. Unfortunately, the ids I have to filter (results of a different party's algorithm) are not same as the FeatureIds. I updated the question.